# Scrape content using cheerio and javascript

Tags: javascript, cheerio

Given the following HTML content on a page:

```
       <div class="this-bold this-orange this-big">Latest Reading: 73&deg; <span class="this-smaller this-itlaic">(updated: July 21, 2021)</span></div><br />
```

I need to be able to scrape and return a string like:

"73 degrees, updated: July, 21, 2021"

How would I accomplish this in javascript using axios and cheerio?

The source URL for the HTML is: https://www.keukalakeassociation.org/charts/keuka_lake_temperature.php

I appreciate your help!

Comment: This is a very general question with plenty of documentation. I recommend taking a look at using "puppeteer" to get this done

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex... something along the lines of this regex

```
\<div class\=\"this-bold this-orange this-big\">([^\<]*)\<.*(updated: [^\)]*)
```

would help you extract something along the lines of this, using capture groups 1 and 2

```
Latest Reading: 73&deg;  updated: July 22, 2021
```

Comment: Thx - What cheerio selector/syntax would I use along with that to find this line in the source HTML?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, but if you have access to the html content of the page in question, you could use that as a string and would't be using cheerio at all for parsing, 

if you want to use cheerio specifically, I'm sure someone with experience doing so will stumble on this soon

Comment: just using regex against the entire page returned worked fine - thanks a bunch

Comment: You want `$('.this-bold.this-orange.this-big').text()` - it will also convert that html entity for you